# Build size is much larger than what's logged in editor.log

Tags: unity-game-engine

to my knowledge the "Complete size" value in the editor log should be the total size of my build. But as you can see from the screenshot below, my editor.log is saying that the "Completed size" is 27.7MB, while the build size in the file system is actually 145MB. Am I missing something here, or am I doing something wrong? Thanks in advance!

**Editor.log screenshot:**

[image]

**Screenshot of size in the file system:**

[image]

Comment: Complete size includes only assets and your compiled Assembly-CSharp

Answer (score 1):

See the links,

1. Build options can make different size for outputs.  such as Arm, Fat and etc.. 
   [image] etc..
2. "Resources", "Streaming Assets" directory are not included in Editor.log file. so check that your project directories, If you have, output size will be bigger than description of Editor.log file.

Comment: Actually, going by your comment, I noticed that the Texture size that the log is claiming is WAY too small. I know that I have around 20MB of textures in the Asset folder. Do you have any idea why those aren't showing up in the log? I am not streaming anything, and I am not using any "Resources" except the assets in the asset folder. :(